# Javascript math issue with custom calculator

Tags: javascript, math

I am having a problem editing a custom calculator for a product calculations.

I created a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9PUmx/4/)

Use calculate button "not order now"

Customers choose 1 field only to calculate cost.

I want to be able to show an alert if the number of pallets is greater than 4.

Everything is based on the number of bags (numbags). You will be able to see the source of what I was trying.

I am not sure if it is where I put the if statement or a combination of that and just not writing it correctly.

I tried :

```
if (palettes >= 4)
        {
            alert('Please call for pricing');
            return false;
        }
```

but it only gives me the alert if I input 1334 or more in the pallet field and click calculate button.

I also tried to

```
if ((palettes >= 885.00) && (numBags >= 300))
        {
            alert('Please call for pricing');
            return false;
        }
```

the number of bags in a pallet is 75, so I thought minimally if I tried using the price of 4 pallets (300 bags * 2.95) which is 885.00, I might get the result I wanted.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((palettes >= 4) || (numBags >= 300))
        {
            alert('Please call for pricing');
            return false;
        }
```

It should be an OR not an AND

Comment: As the price 885 is for 300 bags, we only need to check one of these, not either or both of them!

It should rather be if(numBags >= 300) { //show alert }

Comment: You should be able to check the number of palettes or the number of bags depending which is entered

Comment: I think I got it working through some of the suggestions here. I didn't need the discount price based on volume that I had. So I omitted the the price breaks and changed the code to: // Price calculation
  `var niPrice = numBags * 2.95;
  var iPrice = numBags * 4.95;
  var palettes = Math.floor(numBags / 75);
  
  if ((palettes > 4) || (numBags > 300))
  {
   alert('Please call for pricing');
   return false;
  }`  **this is working great**

Comment: Both are the same conditions, just having one will be enough! And make double sure that the variable in that condition is initialized and has the correct value before checking.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to revisit your logic carefully.

The variable palettes is initialized in the else block. And else{} happens only when `numBags <= 99999` is false. So, when palette field is 1334,

> numbags = 1334 * 75 = 100050

, just more than 99999 and so palettes variable is initialized and your alert is shown.

So, when palettes is less than 1334, the else block is never executed and alert is not shown.

Comment: You make a good point. how could I do this so that if pallets are more than 4 then they will always show the alert?

Comment: Not only now, but anytime, make sure that a variable is initialized and has a value before you check for the condition.